# How do I create number sequence in array with length limit and number limit?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Pease help me to solve this problems:

Given `x` and `y`.

Case 1 : `x = 10` and `y = 4;`

`// x represents the array length and y represents allowed number limit in array`

Should return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Case 2 : `x = 13` and `y = 3;`

Should return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]`

`x` and `y` should be dynamic

Comment: Your question will be downvoted as you are looking for an answer without trying to solve the problem yourself. You need to show some effort of what you've tried yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
function createNumberSequenceInArray(x, y) {
    let p = 0;
    let result = [];
    while (result.length < x) {

        if (p > y) {
            p = 0;
        }
        result.push(p);
        p++;
    }
    return result;
}

createNumberSequenceInArray(10,4);
```